# How to exclude swapfile from rsync backup?

Tags: shell-script, shell, rsync, backup

I'm trying to write a simple script that would back up my system files. Here's what I wrote so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

if [ $UID != 0 ]; then
        echo "Please run me as root"
        exit 1;
fi

src="/"
dest="/mnt/system_backup/"

rsync --archive \
        --acls \
        --xattrs \
        --hard-links \
        --delete \
        --verbose \
        --filter="merge system_backup.filter" \
        $src $dest
```

And here's my `system_backup.filter` file:

```
# Patterns to exclude
- swapfile
- /dev/*
- /proc/*
- /sys/*
- /tmp/*
- /run/*
- /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*
- /mnt/*
- /lost+found
- /home/*
```

For some reason swapfile doesn't get excluded from the backup, however other directories that I listed in this file do (I can see it in the logs if I run `--dry-run` with a second `--verbose` argument). How do I exclude swapfile?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The filter file is particular about its whitespace. For example, after the leading `-`  (dash, space) *everything* is a relevant character. This includes trailing space.

You can check the filter file for such unexpected whitespace with `cat -e system_backup.filter` (not POSIX, but you can use `sed -n l system_backup.filter`). Here's example output showing a single space character after `swapfile` (the `$` indicates end-of-line):

```
# Patterns to exclude$
- swapfile $
- /dev/*$
- /proc/*$
- /sys/*$
- /tmp/*$
- /run/*$
- /var/cache/pacman/pkg/*$
- /mnt/*$
- /lost+found$
- /home/*$
```

Another potential character of interest is `^M` (or `\r` if using `sed`), typically at the end of line, which show a Windows-style CR/LF line ending. For example,

```
- /mnt/*^M$
```

---

As an aside, remember to double-quote your variables when you use them (in case they contain spaces, etc.). So at the end of your `rsync` command, `rsync … "$src" "$dst"`

Comment: Instead of manually excluding `/dev`, `/proc` and whatever, you may find `-x` option more convenient.

Comment: @iBug That's good advice in general, but it also requires them to run `rsync` once on each individual filesystem.